# Font/SSH interaction?

Tags: ssh, tmux, fonts

I use tmux, and tmuxline which uses the powerline fonts to look pretty.
[image: tmuxline working]

The problem is that when I ssh into a server, the font doesn't work.
[image: tmuxline nonworking]

I installed the fonts as according to [these instructions](http://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html#fontconfig).

How do I even start debugging this?

Comment: I would check that the remote server has the correct terminfo and locale set...

Comment: @jasonwryan Yeah, that was it. Locale was en_US instead of en_US.UTF-8

Comment: You should write that up as an answer (with a little more of the gory details, naturally)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) suggested, it was actually a locale issue.

The client was using `en_US.UTF-8`, while the server was using `en_US`. Not entirely clear on *why* it matters, but whatever it works.

For slackware, to set it globally, modify `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh`, as specified [here](http://docs.slackware.com/slackware:localization)

To just modify it on a per user basis, just set `LANG` in your `.bashrc` or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

For the benefit of those searching for a solution to this, or to a similar issue, the above answer led me onto what solved the problem for me on FreeBSD. Adding in the ssh server's `sshd_config`:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE
```

had the effect of enabling me to see the Powerline font glyphs in a ssh+tmux session started using:

```
ssh user@host -t "tmux attach || tmux new -s ssh"
```

Interestingly, this issue only surfaced when using the `ssh -t` (force pseudoterminal) option, not when starting tmux after plain sshing into the server.

Comment: Currently having this issue on freebsd, turns out `ssh -t` fixes it, but the sshd_config entry does not. Well then, just thought that was curious, I'll go on debugging this then.

Comment: I had the same issue with `ssh -t` having `$LANG` empty, as opposed to normal `ssh`. In my case, `AcceptEnv` didn't help, but I could manually set `$LANG` in the `ssh` command, i.e. `ssh user@host -t 'export LANG=blah; command'`